# OSSEC install, can't remove file

Tags: bash

I was following some instructions on the OSSEC site on how to install it on CentOS.

```
  # wget -q -O – https://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
  # yum install ossec-hids ossec-hids-server (or ossec-hids-client for the agent)
```

After I ran the first command, I noticed a file named - appear in my folder. The second command doesn't work as Yum says it can't find the package. But now this strange file - can't be removed. It is actually a pointer to stdout.

Can anyone help please get rid of it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the dash (`-`) you have used in not the regular `-` used to indicate STDOUT:

```
% printf '–' | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 93                                          |...|
00000003

% printf '\xe2\x80\x93\n'
–
```

Regular `-`:

```
% printf '-' | hexdump -C
00000000  2d                                                |-|
00000001

% printf '\x2d\n'        
-
```

So you need to use regular `-` to indicate STDOUT for saving the content.

To remove the created file, use Hex value:

```
rm -- $'\xe2\x80\x93'
```